# Vagrant provisioning + SHH Forwarding + private Git repository -> error during provisioning, but works in user space

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant

I am running an fairly old vagrant 1.2.7.

My setup is the following:

- Windows Host with SSH Agent and Forwarding enabled.
- Forwarding works and I have checked within the vagrant box a "vagrant" and "root" user, both show the key, when doing `ssh-add -l`
- Therefore I have applied that `Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` fix to sudoers.d, so forwarding will propagate to root
- my target server is in known_hosts file
- Target: Having a puppet script, that accesses a private git repository and gets the files
- Running the puppet script after loading vagrant every thing works just fine. Files get pulled via that forwarded ssh key. SSH -v tells me so

But: during provision this won't work. I will get the following error:

```
err: /Stage[main]/Git::Clone/Vcsrepo[/vagrant/repo]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/bin/su vagrant -c git clone user@server.com:~/myrepo.git /vagrant/repo' returned 128: Cloning into /vagrant/repo'...
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I do not fully understand why this is happening.
To my knowledge, having ssh keys forwarded to a privileged user is discouraged. However, I thought this could be circumvented by doing all that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` business.

Does anybody have an idea, what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same challenge in work for a Vagrant dev box that I was putting together.

It turned out that my Mac accommodated ssh etc fine, which is as you might expect, Windows on the other hand struggled and in the end I have to find an alternative.

The alternative is to set up an access token for your github account (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use)) then all you do is use that to access your private repo.

One point that is worth mentioning is that if you are a part of a dev team, or others are making changes to the same repo, then you will want to set up ssh-ing to github afterwards as you will not be able to identify who has made changes etc.

Hope that helps.